# Array out of bounds and null pointer exceptions

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I'm getting an array out of bounds exception. I know its because the array is empty but I do a check on the length before I try to use its contents. But it won't even do the check because its saying the array is causing a null pointer exception. Anyone any ideas why its throwing this up?

Here's the code

```
 private void createGroupTree(ArrayList<String> groupList) throws JWNLException {

    WordNetMeasures wordNet = new WordNetMeasures();
    String[] wordResult;

    for(int i = 0; i<groupList.size(); i++) {
        wordResult = wordNet.getWordNetPath(groupList.get(i));

    if(wordResult.length == 0) {
        graph.addVertex(groupList.get(i));
    } else {
       for(int j=0; j<wordResult.length; j++) {
        if(j !=wordResult.length-1) {
            graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), wordResult[j], wordResult[j+1]);
        }
    } 
    }   

    }           
}
```

Here's the code for the getWordNetPath method that is causing this issues. I know some words in the list are not in the dictionary being used I just don't know how to handle to issue its causing.

```
public String[] getWordNetPath(String word) throws JWNLException {

        RiWordnet wordnet = new RiWordnet();
        //String wordOne = "dog";
        String[] posOfWord = wordnet.getPos(word);
        int[]wordIds = wordnet.getSenseIds(word, posOfWord[0]);
        String[] wordResults = wordnet.getHypernymTree(wordIds[0]);

        return wordResults;
    }
```

Comment: You might be interested in [this debugging tutorial for java beginners](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/). I wrote it to help people to get started with basic debugging.

Comment: Either you're getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException *or* you're getting a NullPointerException. You can't be getting both. It doesn't help that you haven't told us where you're getting the exception - and it also doesn't help that your code is nastily indented :(

Comment: I am getting both. I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds on the line wordResult = wordNet.getWordNetPath(groupList.get(i)) and I'm getting the nullPointer on the line if(wordResult.length==0). Sorry about the indentation... I fix it all once I'm finished coding.. strange method but its just the way I do it

Comment: @user3469624 Actually, you're not getting both since program execution stops at the first exception. Do you mean for different data?

Comment: I am getting both at different times. Sometimes it stops at the first line and sometimes it stops at the second one I mentioned. This is why I'm confused...

Comment: You will get a `NullPointer` if `getWordNetPath` returns `null`, and also the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` can't be thrown by `groupList.get(i)`, so it too must be due to something within `getWordNetPath`. So the aforementioned method is the interesting one here.

Answer (score 2):

If `wordNet.getWordNetPath(groupList.get(i));` returns `null`, that would cause a `NullPointerException` in the next statement when the code tries to evaluate `wordResult.length`. You should change the `if` to:

```
if(wordResult == null || wordResult.length == 0) {
    graph.addVertex(groupList.get(i));
} else {
    . . .
```

You'll have to post the stack trace for us to diagnose the array out of bounds exception. The code you posted should not be generating that (although it might come from within one of the methods you are calling). As an aside, you can eliminate the `if` inside the inner loop (on index `j`) by rewriting it as:

```
for(int j=0; j<wordResult.length - 1; j++) {
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), wordResult[j], wordResult[j+1]);
}
```

EDIT: Based on your comment that the array bounds exception is coming from this line:

```
wordResult = wordNet.getWordNetPath(groupList.get(i));
```

I suspect that `groupList.get(i)` is returning some value that causes `getWordNetPath` to throw the exception. The answer lies somewhere in code that you haven't posted. If you don't want to bother tracking down the source of the exception and simply want to allow your program to continue in the event one is thrown, you can simply catch it:

```
try {
    wordResult = wordNet.getWordNetPath(groupList.get(i));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    wordResult = null;
}
```

If you're also getting `NullPointerException` sometimes thrown from `getWordNetPath`, you can add a second `catch` clause for that as well.

Comment: When I place the extra check in the if statement I'm still getting the NullPointerException which is baffling me as this should cover the states this array could be in

Comment: @user3469624 - It's impossible that the `if` test I wrote is still generating a NPE. Are you sure it's still coming from the same line? Are you sure that you correctly rebuilt the project and are running the updated code?

Comment: I know there are some words that groupList.get(i) returns that are not found in the dictionary I am using and this is what's causing the issue I am having. I just don't know how to handle this so the system can continue executing when this occurs. I will add the code behind this to my original post now.

Comment: @user3469624 - I don't see exactly where the exception would be thrown in `getWordNetPath`, but I added some code and a bit of explanation to my answer to show how you can continue executing when the exception is thrown.

Comment: I have added in the try catch statements like you suggested and I'm still getting a NullPointerException when I check if wordResults in length 0 or null in the code. I've debugged this and in the getWordNetPath method the wordResult array is null before its returned so I don't understand why this exception is being thrown.

Comment: @user3469624 - Please check your code. Make sure that the test for `null` is the first test. That is, you should be using `if (wordResult == null || wordResult.length == 0)` and **not** `if (wordResult.length == 0 || wordResult == null)`. Order matters because the `||` operator evaluates its left operand first.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. A try catch had to be added around the whole block of code. This means for the words that are not contained in the dictionary the NullPointerException is caught and it moves onto the next word in the list.

The words that are compatible are added to the graph and the incompatible ones are not added.